# Once the rotor reaches saturation in a linear motor, do further increases in B increase acceleration?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, ferromagnetism

I need to accelerate a chunk of steel with a solenoid.

I calculated the B field in the bore of the solenoid, and it is > 3 T.

Most definitions of saturation place the saturation of steel around 1.5 or 2 T.

Here is my question:

I know that further increasing the magnetic field cannot store additional energy in the core. Does that mean that further increasing the magnetic field cannot increase acceleration on the steel?

Comment: Is this for a coilgun? In that case, the time-dependence and inhomogeneity of the magnetic field will likely be more significant than considerations like saturation.

Comment: @catalogue_number can you tell me more about the time-dependence and inhomogeneity?

Comment: Ján's answer is correct for a magnetostatic situation, in which you have a small magnetised body moving in a fixed external magnetic field. If the magnetic field changes in time, then you will also need to think about the eddy currents induced in the (presumably conductive) sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magnetic force on magnetized body can be (in the simplest case) expressed as

$$
\mathbf F = \mathbf m \cdot \nabla \mathbf B_{ext}
$$
which means force is proportional to magnetic moment of the body $\mathbf  m$ and also to gradient of the external magnetic field $\mathbf B_{ext}$, and the body is attracted to regions of stronger magnetic field.

When increasing strength of the external field from zero, before saturation of the body, both magnetic moment of the body and external field increase. So in your case where the external magnetic field is due to current in the coils, the force gets stronger quicker than linearly with electric current.

Saturation means the magnetic moment does not increase or only very little when external field gets stronger, so further increase of current will increase only $\mathbf B_{ext}$, and $\mathbf m$ will remain close to constant. So the force will increase still, but only linearly with current.

If this magnetic force is the dominant force on the body, the body will accelerate due to it, and of course, stronger net force implies higher acceleration.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! Thank you! :)